# how to a zoom option to my wpf app?

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming

I'm working on wpf application , the application draws the countours on an existing image and i want to add a button which give me the hand to zoom the image to see the countours

i added a button and a fonction on .cs but it doesn't work

here's the code cs

```
namespace AnimationTest
{
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = 0;
        da.To = 1000;
        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        image1.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.CenterXProperty, da);

    }
}
```

}

and XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationTest.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="1280">
<Grid>
    <Image Height="681" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1258" Source="/AnimationTest;component/Images/world.jpg" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1171,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

what's the problem ? and how can i fixe it ?

thanks

Comment: Probably you want to animate ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty. ScaleTransform.CenterXProperty defines the center of the scale transform. If you change it but the scale is set to 1 you won't see any result.

Comment: i didn't understant , please can you explain

Comment: Actually i was wrong. This has no sens `image1.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.CenterXProperty, da);` You start an animation on an image of a property that don't belong to Image control. You should create a scale transform, attache it to the image and then start an animation on scale transform object, not image.

Comment: @Didier, that's the right answer.  I suggest you change your comment to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has no sens `image1.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.CenterXProperty, da);` You start an animation on an image of a property that don't belong to Image control. You should create a scale transform, set it on the image and then start the animation on scale transform object, not the image.